# how to fix mycakephp3 program in ubuntu 14.04 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable

Tags: ubuntu, cakephp, ubuntu-14.04, cakephp-3.0

I copied all my files in my windows laptop which my cakephp program functioning already but when Im in my ubuntu machine it says below.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mycake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/functions.php on line 26

I could not find any solution on this  [forum](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10035)

Im using cakephp 3.4.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the variadic argument token (`...`) that the parser complains about, and the solution to the problem can be found in the issue report that you've linked:

> CakePHP 3.4 requires PHP 5.6+

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10035#issuecomment-272607697**

Upgrade your PHP version to at least `5.6.0`.

See also **[Cookbook > Installation > Requirements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements)**

Comment: Thank you so much i updated my version of xammp for linux